# Passing variable to controller - if null value, display alert instead

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I want to do something like the following in a visualforce page

```
<apex:inputTextarea id="abc" 
        value="if('abc'.value().size()>0,alert('Hi'),{!AModel.Comment.Body}"
```

Can anyone tell me how to achieve this

I want to display an alert if the entered value is null. else I want to pass it to the controller.

Comment: why don't you just check the `AModel.Comment.Body` this is null or not in your controller and show error message. else when you try to submit/save the page. before calling the controller method, call a javascript function there check this field is empty or not. and based on that show alert message

Comment: That is not possible actually... The error message has to come in an alert box.

Comment: what is not possible? the controller validation or javascript alert message?

Comment: It has to be a javascript alert message. It cant be a controller validation.

Comment: Please edit your question to make it more clear. Your title asks about passing the variable only when it's value is not null, but your comments talk about creating an alert via JS when it is null to prevent it from being passed. Those are two very different questions.

Comment: You are saying that you want to pass it to controller, What is the Action that you are specifying? like any apex:commandButton?

Comment: @Subhash Yes...it is a command button

Comment: Use the Ratan's code of Javascript in a Function and Call that function from the Onclick of Command Button...

Comment: @Rimii is this issue resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a javascript validation like below

```
<apex:inputTextarea id="abc" 
        value="{!AModel.Comment.Body}" />
```

in javascript

```
var commentBodyVal = document.getElementById('{!$Component.abc}').value;
if(commentBodyVal.trim().length == 0 )
{
    alert('Your text area field is empty. Please add something.');
}
else {
   //call action function to call your controller method
}
```

Comment: document.getElementById('{!$Component.abc}').value statement is throwing an error.. it it saying cannot read the .value property of null @Ratan

Comment: @Rimii may be your component is inside multiple VF tags that s why it is not able to access .. check this doc https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_component.htm

Comment: @Rimii your id may be like this `{!$Component.theBlock.theSection.theSectionItem.theText}` multi component ids

Comment: @Rimii is tis question still open ?

Comment: no the question is not open